# Not Equal to in php not working

Tags: php, for-loop, operators

I have String :

```
 $food="7:1,address:mandakini Pune,clusterid:1,email:s@gmail.com,mobile:950389,name:san,valid_order_id:FD1445853852";
```

I split this string by ',' using `$items = explode ( ",", $food );`
  When i am trying to read it like

```
for($i=0;$i < sizeof($items);$i++){
    $jsonval= $items[$i];

    $inneritems = explode ( ":", $jsonval );
    $item1=$inneritems[0];
    $item2=$inneritems[1];

    echo '<br/>items '.$item1.":".$item2.'<br/>';
    if($item1 !="clusterid" || $item1!="name" || $item1!="email" || $item1!="mobile" || $item1!="address" || $item1!="valid_order_id"){
        echo 'hello '.$item1.":".$item2;
    }
}
```

I am getting following output:

```
 items 7:1 
 hello 7:1
 items address:mandakini Pune
 hello address:mandakini Pune
 items clusterid:1
 hello clusterid:1
 items email:s2@gmail.com
 hello email:s@gmail.com
 items mobile:950389
 hello mobile:950389
 items name:san
 hello name:san 
 items valid_order_id:FD1445853852
 hello valid_order_id:FD1445853852'
```

and my expected output is:

```
items 7:1
 hello 7:1
```

Comment: Use !== instead of !=

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `&&` instead of `||` ?

Comment: I doubt != is not working (or if it isn't then it's because of type-juggling which can easily be fixed with !==), I suspect your if logic is wrong in some aspect.  You might want to think about exactly what you're trying to achieve and what conditions must be met for that to happen

Comment: && worked. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this with `&&` instead of `||` in if

[Onlie Demo](https://ideone.com/9PnHdr)

```
$food="7:1,address:mandakini Pune,clusterid:1,email:s@gmail.com,mobile:950389,name:san,valid_order_id:FD1445853852";
 $items = explode ( ",", $food );
 for($i=0;$i < sizeof($items);$i++){
    $jsonval= $items[$i];

    $inneritems = explode ( ":", $jsonval );
    $item1=$inneritems[0];
    $item2=$inneritems[1];

    // echo '<br/>items '.$item1.":".$item2.'<br/>';
    if($item1 !="clusterid" && $item1!="name" && $item1!="email" && $item1!="mobile" && $item1!="address" && $item1!="valid_order_id"){
        echo '<br/>items '.$item1.":".$item2.'<br/>';
        echo 'hello '.$item1.":".$item2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($item1 !="clusterid" || $item1!="name" || $item1!="email" || $item1!="mobile" || $item1!="address" || $item1!="valid_order_id"){
    echo 'hello '.$item1.":".$item2;
}
```

should be using &&.

```
if($item1 !="clusterid" && $item1!="name" && $item1!="email" && $item1!="mobile" && $item1!="address" && $item1!="valid_order_id"){
    echo 'hello '.$item1.":".$item2;
}
```

Actually, if you want exactly your expected output, you should put the

```
echo '<br/>items '.$item1.":".$item2.'<br/>';
```

also inside the if. Now you will get 7 items and 1 hello.

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
if($item1 == 7 && $item2 == 1){
    echo 'hello '.$item1.":".$item2;
}
```

OR

```
if($item1 !="clusterid" && $item1!="name" && $item1!="email" && $item1!="mobile" && $item1!="address" && $item1!="valid_order_id"){
    echo 'hello '.$item1.":".$item2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($item1 !="clusterid" || $item1!="name" || $item1!="email" || $item1!="mobile" || $item1!="address" || $item1!="valid_order_id"){
        echo 'hello '.$item1.":".$item2;
    }
```

This mean if the item isn't "clusterid" **OR** the item isn't "name" **OR** the item isn't "email" etc etc.

If the item, for example, is "clusterid" then the first condition is false, but the second is true - and because you've used the **or** operand it will meet the true condition.

Use **and** instead of **or**:

```
if($item1 !="clusterid" && $item1!="name" && $item1!="email" && $item1!="mobile" && $item1!="address" && $item1!="valid_order_id"){
        echo 'hello '.$item1.":".$item2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your expected output:

```
items 7:1
hello 7:1
```

You might consider to make your code a bit more readable:

```
$filter = ['clusterid', 'name', 'email', 'mobile', 'address', 'valid_order_id'];
$items = explode(',', $food);

foreach($items as $value) {
    $innerItems = explode (':', $value);

    if (!in_array($innerItems[0], $filter)) {
        echo 'items ' . $innerItems[0] . ':' . $innerItems[1] . '<br>'
           . 'hello ' . $innerItems[0] . ':' . $innerItems[1] . '<br>';
    }    
}
```

Using `in_array` seems to be easier to maintain and better to read than a long logical expression. Also note that the loop is only necessary if the position of the value `7:1` isn't determined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you split each item by the colon(:).
To get the value you are currently checking for, you would need to split the first part (before the colon) by space too, and take the second part of that.

Other wise the line is:

```
items clusterid
```

and not

```
clusterid
```

which is what you are checking for.

Also, move the first echo into the if statement.

Try this:

```
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($items); $i++){
    $jsonval= $items[$i];

    list($item1, $item2) = explode(":", $jsonval);
    list($part1, $part2) = explode(" ", $item1);
    $badArray = array('clusterid', 'name', 'email', 'mobile', 'address', 'valid_order_id');

    if(!in_array($part2, $badArray)){
        echo '<br/>items '.$item1.":".$item2.'<br/>';
        echo 'hello '.$item1.":".$item2;
    }
}
```